# Can't access video (getUserMedia) from a Visualforce Page (opened from LWC)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, iframe

I have a **LWC** which opens **Visualforce Page** in modal window.
And in that Visualforce Page I want to get access to a camera.
For it I use  `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia))

However I am getting  " **DOMException: Permission denied** " error message :

My LWC :

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card >
        <p slot="title">Test</p>
        <lightning-button label="Test" variant="brand" slot="actions" onclick={showModal}></lightning-button>
        <div slot="footer"></div>
    </lightning-card>
    <template if:true={showCloudinaryModal}>
        <div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-backdrop">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src={visualforcePage}></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

The simplest Visualforce Page which does not work :

```html
<apex:page>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) {
                console.log("Let's get this party started");
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then( (result) => {
                    console.log('getUserMedia result: ',result);
                }).catch( (error) =>{
                    console.error('getUserMedia error: ',error);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

the **error** which I am getting "*DOMException: Permission denied*" :

[image]

My Dev org and the Visualforce Page **have access** to camera.

And it works if you try to **open the Visualforce Page in other window** or if you embed the Visualforce Page into **another** Visualforce Page using **iframe**.

Am I **missing** something ?
Is it something with **Lightning Locker** ?

I tried to enable **Lightning Web Security** for LWC, however it didn't help.

*Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

As Visualforce pages are serverd from a different domain, you have to allow that permissions on the iFrame:

```
<iframe allow="camera; microphone" src={mysrc}/>
```

Here is a related question (not LWC + Visualforce)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008648/accessing-camera-and-mic-in-sandboxed-iframe-from-different-subdomain

Comment: Thanks for your response and it actually make sense. I added **allow="camera; microphone"**, however the result is the same. I still get  DOMException: Permission denied